# How to find $A,B,C$ such that $M=A^2+B^2+C^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

> Let $M=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \in M_{2}(\mathbb Z)$, prove that there exist
>   $A,B,C \in M_{2}(\mathbb Z)$ such that $M=A^2+B^2+C^2$.

My idea: if we can find $a_{i},b_{i},c_{i},d_{i}\in \mathbb Z,i=1,2,3$ such

$$a=a^2_{1}+a^2_{2}+a^2_{3}$$
$$b=b^2_{1}+b^2_{2}+b^2_{3}$$
$$c=c^2_{1}+c^2_{2}+c^2_{3}$$
$$d=d^2_{1}+d^2_{2}+d^2_{3}$$

then we prove it. But I can't find such numbers. Thank you.

This problem is from this paper: (has a solution)  (45)
http://mathproblems-ks.com/?wpfb_dl=8

And in fact I want to see other methods? Thank you (because I think this problem has other methods.)

Comment: You seem to think that the square of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$ is $\begin{bmatrix}a^2&b^2\\c^2&d^2\end{bmatrix}$, but it's not. Its square is $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}a^2+bc&ab+bd\\ac+cd&bc+d^2\end{bmatrix}$.$

Answer (score 3):

The proof is found in Granville's paper [Matrices as the sum of four squares](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/4squares.pdf) of $1987$, see Lemma $2$. 
The proof is elementary, but perhaps not entirely obvious. Moreover
it is shown that $-I_2$ really needs $3$ squares, and that every integral matrix of size $n\ge 3$ is the sum of $4$ squares.